# Using a custom UI for a QGIS processing algorithm script

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3, pyqt5

In QGIS 2.x I have a PyQGIS script that utilises a custom form created in Qt Designer. I could simply call the form and connect a button to a function with the following:

```
class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    myForm = uic.loadUi('ui_file.ui')

    def doSomething(self):
        print 'Hello World'

myWidget = MyWidget()
searchButton = myWidget.myForm.findChildren(QtGui.QWidget, 'searchButton')[0]
searchButton.pressed.connect(myWidget.doSomething)
myWidget.show()
```

I'm now trying to update this script for use in QGIS 3.4, which now requires processing scripts to be written by extending the `QgsProcessingAlgorithm` class. I've used the template script as described in the [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html), and used [createCustomParametersWidget()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingAlgorithm.html#ab8c8eb508bd422c98a662eb5f904563d) to show my custom ui in place of the default form.

However, I can't figure out how to get the signal/slot code to work correctly. I've tried defining the signal in the `createCustomParametersWidget` function and in the `initAlgorithm` function. When the script is run, the custom form shows, but the button is not connected.

```
class MyTool(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):  

    INPUT = 'INPUT'
    OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT' 

   class MyWidget(QWidget):
        myForm = uic.loadUi('ui_file.ui')

        def exec_ (self):
            exec_ = self.myForm.show()

        def doSomething(self):
            print('hello World!')

    def createCustomParametersWidget(self, QWidget): 
        myWidget = self.MyWidget()
        searchButton = myWidget.myForm.findChildren(QToolButton, 'searchButton')[0] #also tried this in initAlgorithm()
        searchButton.pressed.connect(myWidget.doSomething)
```

It seems the `initAlgorithm` takes a configuration parameter (but I can't find any documentation on how to set this up, and this may not be the solution anyway).

Could anybody offer a code snippet on how to make this work in QGIS 3.4, or some links to some further information on how to the this up correctly? If possible, I want to avoid making this into a fully fledged plugin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see the practical side of creating classes inside other classes. Just split it.

Below is how I will make your code work :

```py
import os
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm

os.chdir("/home/julien/Bureau/")

FORM_CLASS, _ = uic.loadUiType("ui_file.ui")


class MyWidget(QWidget, FORM_CLASS):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        # signals
        self.searchButton.pressed.connect(self.doSomething)

    def doSomething(self):
        print('hello World!')


class MyTool(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    INPUT = 'INPUT'
    OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'

    def createCustomParametersWidget(self): 
        self.myWidget = MyWidget()
        self.myWidget.show()


my_alg = MyTool()
my_alg.createCustomParametersWidget()
```