# How to Group Parameters in PyQGIS Processing Plugin

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, gui

The PyQGIS Processing Plugin I'm writing has a lot of parameters, most of which are advanced and won't be necessary for most users. I'm concerned that a user will be confused if they see all these parameters that they don't know what to do with. Is there a way I can group parameters in a collapseable "advanced parameters" box in the plugin's GUI similarly to how the 'Round raster' built-in processing program does?

Comment: You would need to create a custom UI for your algorithm. [Here's a starting point.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/356729/using-a-custom-ui-for-a-qgis-processing-algorithm-script)

Answer (score 6):

It's not clear to me if you are using PyQGIS. It's not mentioned in your question.
If you are using only the GUI, then it's only when you create a model, so when you add an input, you can choose if yes or not it's an advanced parameter.

If you are using PyQGIS, you can define with a "flag". In the `initAlgorithm` function of your script, for the specific parameter :

```
    param = QgsProcessingParameterString(
        self.NAME_OF_THE_PARAMETER,
        tr('Your label'),
        optional=False,
        defaultValue='If any default')

    # The line below will take default flags already there and adds the Advanced one

    param.setFlags(param.flags() | QgsProcessingParameterDefinition.FlagAdvanced)
    self.addParameter(param)
```

Comment: I am using PyQGIS and clarified my question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I came to this question with high hopes for a more general solution to arranging large numbers of parameters in a PyQGIS Processing tool, but was disappointed by the focus on exposing the 'Advanced Parameters' group.

Whilst 'Advanced Parameters' has been covered in the answer from @etrimaille I'll add another tip that I have found more generally useful, that the parameter label text will render HTML tags.

This allows elements to be added to simulate groups as follows:

From:

[image: Plain parameter labels]

To:

[image: HTML tagged labels]

The parameter text has been changed in the code as follows:

'Polygons Source' has become:

```html
    '<br><b>INPUTS</b><br><br>Polygons Source'
```

'Output layer' has become:

```html
    '<br><hr><b>OUTPUTS</b><br><br>Output layer'
```

The only downside that I have encountered to using this is that the output parameter text is used as a layer name if the output data type is left as temporary, resulting in an ugly layer name.